# response [ts] Property 'Body' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I hope you can help me.
I have a http.get method which I created:

```
return this.http
      .get(url)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        response = response.json(); //
        console.log('The http get response', response);
        return response;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

The response looks like this:

```
{Body: "[{"Id":1,"Name":"Tomato Soup","Category":"Grocerie…e":"Hammer","Category":"Hardware","Price":16.99}]"}
```

My subscribe method of the http.get looks like this:

```
this.azureService.messageBody.subscribe(
      (response: Response) => {
        this.msgBodyDetail = JSON.parse(response.Body);
      }
```

The msgBodyDetail is declared of type string.
There is a typescript error in this line complaining about response.Body:

```
this.msgBodyDetail = JSON.parse(response.Body);

The error is : [ts] Property 'Body' does not exist on type 'Response'.
any
```

The application does not gives an error and the output is as expected.

```
console.log('Response', JSON.parse(response.Body));
```

Results in:

```
Response: 
0 : {Id: 1, Name: "Tomato Soup", Category: "Groceries", Price: 1}
1 : {Id: 2, Name: "Yo-yo", Category: "Toys", Price: 3.75}
2 : {Id: 3, Name: "Hammer", Category: "Hardware", Price: 16.99}
```

Can anybody help me so that I can get rid of the typescript error?

Many thanks,
Lino

Comment: Try `response['Body']` instead of  `response.Body`

Comment: my gosh, so simple..... I feel like a dork :) Can you explain this to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to add to @Amit's answer to explain to you **why** you're having this issue.

```
.map((response: Response) => {
    response = response.json(); //
    console.log('The http get response', response);
    return response;
})
```

As you can see, you declare a parameter `response` of type `Response`.

Because you didn't specify what your function returns, it infers the return type with `Response`, because you're returning the parameter which you reassigned. And since it is an Angular class, it doesn't have a `Body` member.

When you write `response['Body']`, you use the array notation, which gets rid of the typing and accessors : that's why your error disappears.

But it is a workaround, and not a clean solution.

What you should do is type your function, and return the correct type. You can do so like this :

```
messageBody(): Observable<{Body: any[]}> { // You can replace any with a class if you have one
return this.http
  .get(url)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    console.log('The http get response', response);
    return response.json();
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: You should also mention the return type of response inside subscribe block, else that will be a type mismatch error.

Comment: Yes and no : types will mismatch, but because `json()` returns `any`, no error will pop.

Comment: I mean the type of response inside subscribe and the return type of messageBody() will be mismatched

Comment: I know what you meant, and I'm telling you're partially right : there is a mismatch, but because of `response.json()` typed as `any`, it isn't an error (and while we're at it, it isn't a Javascript error, but only a linting error, since Javascript doesn't type variables). I think you didn't see that I changed the code a bit, I'm not returning `response` anymore, only the `json()` part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you map response to `response.json();` you can't set it to type Response anymore in subscribe.

`json();` method returns any so you can set either any as type or create interface for your response.